# Is there a common name in the OCR world for the “halo affect” or the shadow produced when a black background image is binarized?

Tags: opencv, ocr

I have a lot of binary images to OCR.  They were created by binarizing bitmaps where the background was black and text white, but the binarizer was tuned for black text and a white background.

For the vast majority of these, I have no access to the original items or the original bitmaps.

Unfortunately, the binarization process created a binary image with a residual shadow or halo around all of the previously white text.  I think that this is common artifact of white text on black background image binarization and it is an impediment to reading the text using standard OCR techniques.

I want to OCR this kind of shadowed text using OpenCV, but have been unable to find the appropriate terminology to search out solutions, if any, from others with a similar issue.

Does this affect have a common name in the OCR world?

Here is an example of what I am seeing:  Well I cannot yet post photos...  Too new :-)

somewhat related, but not identical to the issue that I describe: 
[How to remove Blur halo effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225004/how-to-remove-blur-halo-effect)
[Sharpening image using OpenCV OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110482/sharpening-image-using-opencv-ocr?rq=1)